# Is there a comparable function in python to R's "which" function?

Tags: python, r, character

The R 'which' function is an efficient and parallelized way to find characters in long strings of character vectors.  Is there a function or simple way to implement this in python?

Comment: Could you add a code sample with input and output, so we can see what exactly you're trying to achieve? On first glance, it seems `map`, `filter` and/or list comprehensions may be able to do the job, but I don't know how powerful `which` is.

Comment: That's not a good description of which. Perhaps a link to the R docs would help. Also, do you want the exact functionality of which, or one specific usage?

Comment: `which` finds in a vector which index corresponds to a given value. What you described is `grep`.

Comment: See [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html) a description of `which`and [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) for `grep`.

Comment: What does efficient and parallelized mean? Naively this would be similar to which `[i for i, c in enumerate(<long_string>) if c in <chars>]`

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way to get the indices of elements in an enumerable collection if those elements satisfy a certain condition is to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) together with [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). For example, to find all the indices of the odd elements in a list:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> [index for index, item in enumerate(mylist) if item%2]
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I also found the ***pandas*** module which, though a little rough around the edges provides a limited application of the boolean vector evaluation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how R works, but here's a few ideas to get you started

```
lookingFor = 'a'
print "the string of all '%s's is" %lookingFor, ''.join(char for char in myLongString if char==lookingFor)
print "there are %s many instances of the character '%s' in the string '%s'" %(myLongString.count(lookingFor), lookingFor, myLongString)
import collections
print "there are %s many instances of the character '%s' in the string '%s'" %(collections.Counter(myLongString)[lookingFor], lookingFor, myLongString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or wrapped into generic function:

```
>>> which = lambda targetList, f: [index for index, item in enumerate(targetList) if f(item)]
```

e.g.:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> which(mylist, lambda x: x % 2)
```